# is it safe to leave apache doc root to /var/www when all your django files are in a different folder?

Tags: django, apache, root, wsgi

I've set up my Apache with mod_wsgi and everything runs perfectly.

There is this bit of code from Apache's configuration, which I dont know how to take.
It clearly says that the document root of the webserver is /var/www.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Because I am running django, I have all my views, models, templates etc in a different folder under /home with www-data ownership.

If my wsgi script is taking care of the django files from /home/ is it safe to leave apache document root to /var/www ?

Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can try [**Deploying static files** in a nutshell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#deploying-static-files-in-a-nutshell). Everything is in the documentation about [**static files management**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

Probably you want to install [**django.contrib.staticfiles**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/). Then if you really want to use /var/www, you can **set MEDIA_ROOT** to /var/www/media **and STATIC_ROOT** to /var/www/static. Then run **./manage.py [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic)**. Eventually **fix the permissions** in /var/www after that.

Comment: I dont follow your answer. Maybe you misunderstood my description: that part of the config is present. I am just wondering what should be done with /var/www when all my files (templates, static files, views, etc) are in /home. Get it?

Comment: ok we are getting somewhere now :) so if i just leave it as it is right now, should be alright ... i've aleady used staticfiles and set my MEDIA and STATIC to different folders under /home ... cheerios!

Comment: Good Job ! ! What's the problem ? can you update the question ?

Comment: Did you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#deploying-static-files-in-a-nutshell ?

Comment: yes ... am I right when I say that if there is no explicit alias in apache for a given url, then that url will be served by mod_wsgi, therefore the document root could be safely set to /var/www because the / url is served by mod_wsgi

Comment: Actually you should set some urls for wsgi, and some for static contents. Example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/#serving-files